# will not-necessary continuous function be constant?

Tags: calculus

Given a real function on the segment $[0, 1]$ such that each point on the segment is either local maximum or local minimum for this function. Is this function a constant?

Comment: Local means 'in some interval'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Take $f(x)=1$ is $x$ is irrational, $f(x)=0$ is $x$ is rational.

Comment: in which interval 1 is local maximum?

Comment: Every interval...

Comment: please, read definition of local maximum once again

Comment: I know what local maximum means. What is your issue?

Comment: Sorry I'm not right. Your answer is correct.

Comment: The same question about continuous function

Comment: @user156035 A Google search gives [this](http://projecteuclid.org/DPubS?verb=Display&version=1.0&service=UI&handle=euclid.rae/1229619424&page=record).